# Automatic login after registration

Tags: authentication, registration

After a user has registered a new account I want the new user of my site to be logged in automatically, i.e. an automatic login after registration. The registration is a JavaScript application. When the registration form is submitted the first request is a POST request to the registration server which contains the username and password. The response of the registration server is either *ok* or *err*. If *ok* is returned the registration JavaScript triggers a second POST request to the login server which again contains the username and password to login the user.

I have chosen this solution as the registration and login server are running on different domains so that the registration server cannot set a session cookie.

Is there any flaw in this solution?

Comment: Why are registration and login running on different domains?  Is that a design decision you made, or something you're stuck with?

Comment: It's a design decision that I cannot change.